# Are my US dollar bank notes still valid and for how long will they be?

Tags: usa, money

I have some  US Dollar  Federal Reserve notes:

Some   12  Federal Reserve Notes  100  Dollar   Notes   Series 2006  A
Some   40  Federal Reserve Notes  100  Dollar   Notes   Series 2009  A

Please tell me whether they're still valid and whether they will continue to be.

Comment: Federal reserve notes are valid indefinitely.  How is your question related to travel?

Comment: Related interest: *[Converting Older United States Dollar Bills](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25959)* and *[Older US dollars not accepted everywhere?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48579)*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to travel (although currency exchange might be).

Comment: How is this question NOT related to travelling? In my travelling it has already happened to me that I had some left over banknotes from my previous visit, and in my next visit some times later they stopped being valid.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, they're still valid, and should never expire. You may find that some places look suspiciously on the old designs for larger bills like that, but you can always trade them in at a bank at no cost.

Comment: I don't know about "you can always trade them in at a bank".  My experience is that banks in the US usually won't provide such services to people who don't have accounts at that bank, which is probably the case for a traveler.

Comment: @NateEldredge but the people looking suspiciously on the old designs are usually outside the US.  I've never had trouble using an old bill in the US.

Comment: @NateEldredge - you can *sometimes* trade them at a bank?  My brothers have reported being able to trade bills for rolls of quarters even at banks they do not have accounts with, and that is basically the same service (trade one form of money for another).  So it might take a bit of asking around, but probably one bank or another can be found that will.

Comment: If a US bank refuses to honor these notes, from _anyone_, then you can simply report them to the FDIC (if it is a credit union to the NCUA) as they are in violation of their basic role in banking.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I wasn't aware that FDIC regulations require a bank to offer such services to non-customers.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: It's has nothing to do with being a customer or not. The currency says its legal form of tender for all debts private and public and banks (other than validating the authenticity of the notes) cannot refuse to service anyone that comes with them. It's kind of the basic tenants of banking. They are of course free to charge you fees and have other reporting / regulatory requirements but they cannot refuse to exchange them.

Comment: I don't think there's any debt involved in this situation, so I don't think the "legal tender" thing is relevant here.

Comment: @NateEldredge Banking regulations aside, I rather suspect that if someone shows up at a bank teller wanting to exchange money, the cost of verifying whether that person has an account exceeds the cost of providing the service to a non-customer.

Comment: @NateEldredge I used to have no problems cashing checks at US banks at which I held no account. But perhaps that is a service to the check-writer rather than to me.

Comment: @Calchas: Yes, it's a service to the check writer. In fact it's really the definition of a check: when it's presented to the bank, by the payee or anyone to whom the payee has endorsed it (e.g. the payee's bank), the bank will pay it.  If they don't they are liable to the writer for [wrongful dishonor](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/4/4-402).  But that's not relevant to the question of whether they will exchange currency.

Answer (score 6):

Every bill and coin ever issued by the US government in its history remains valid and will be valid while the government continues to exist.

At some point, the collector value of a bill or coin will exceed its face value, but with 2006 $100 bill, that will likely be decades or centuries from now.

Comment: This can be true, but some old bills may require special measures to exchange.

Comment: Yes, if they need an expert to authenticate or for some technical reason like that, but the 14th Amendment provides that US debts "shall not be questioned".  The closest thing to an exception was the "Hawaii overprint note", current in Hawaii from 1942 to 1944: each was prominently marked "HAWAII" and if that island chain fell to the Japanese, the notes could have been repudiated _en masse_.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "never" when it comes to government promises...