# Exchanging older United States currency in Japan

Tags: japan, money, exchange

I am traveling to Japan and I want to know if these old 100 USD bills are accepted there for currency exchange.

[image: 100 USD bills]

Comment: Where are you now? You can exchange these at any bank in the USA.

Comment: I am in UAE right now and I am going to japan next week

Comment: I will defer to others, but I have not yet heard of a problem with any of the large-portrait bills, even these that lack new anti-counterfeiting measures. The old small-portrait bills are very hard to use outside the USA, and even there, exchanging at a bank is probably the only thing to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Older United States Dollar Bills](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25959/converting-older-united-states-dollar-bills)

Comment: @Giorgio **This is not a duplicate.** The asker wants to know if those dollar bills will be accepted as a specific destination, not how someone can convert old dollar bills.

Comment: Here is a list of currency exchange service facilities at the Tokyo Narita airport: https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/service/svc_11 maybe contact them and they'll have your answer?

Comment: All US dollars issued since 1914 is legal tender. Plus these don't look old to me in any way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Series 2006A $100 US note is still is circulation and should be accepted by any service or institution that offers foreign money exchange.

Each Japanese international [airport has foreign currency exchange services](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/service/svc_11), as do many large hotels. Major banks exchange foreign currency and many have branches in airports and train stations, with the following as just a few of the many available:

- [The Bank of Tokyo-Mitsubishi UFJ](http://www.bk.mufg.jp/global/?link_id=p_top_head_global)
- [Mizuho Bank](https://www.mizuhobank.com/index.html)
- [Sumitomo Mitsui Banking Corporation](http://www.smbc.co.jp/global/)
- [Japan Post Bank](https://www.jp-bank.japanpost.jp/en_index.html)
- [SMBC Trust Bank](https://www.smbctb.co.jp/en/)
- [MUFG Bank](http://www.bk.mufg.jp/global/)

Comment: is there a way of telling by looking at a note what series they are? Furthermore is there a government website where it states which series are still legal tender and time frame they will be still legal tender?

Comment: @3kstc I didn't look in detail, but https://www.uscurrency.gov/acceptance-and-use-older-design-federal-reserve-notes might be a starting point.

Comment: @3kstc There’s no need for a website — all US treasury notes ever issued are still legal tender. But that doesn’t necessarily mean that a foreign bureau de change will accept them.

Comment: @3kstc: the series is printed between the portrait and one of the signature blocks at the bottom of the face, thus to left or right of the bottom of the portrait. The ones shown here are to the left and say 'SERIES 2006 A' and 'SERIES 2003'. Except for $1 and $2 the series is also indicated by the first letter in the serial (before the letter indicating the FRB region), see https://www.bep.gov/currency/serial-numbers